# Showing DialogFragment from RecyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment that I want to show when clicking on an item inside a Recycler View. Here are my files:

DialogFragment.kt:

```
class TaskDialogFragment:DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        var rootView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_dialog, container, false)
        return  rootView

    }
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.kt:

```
class RecycleViewAdapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var dao: TaskDao
    private lateinit var dialogFragment: TaskDialogFragment

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
                // this is where I want my dialogFragment to be opened from
                dialogFragment = TaskDialogFragment()
                dialogFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, "taskDialog")
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried following the steps shown here https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/dialogs but I get an error saying `Unresolved Reference: supportFragmentManager`.

How would I open this dialog from the recycler view? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use callback for it or pas activity refrence to adapter then   dialogFragment.show(mActivity.supportFragmentManager,"taskDailog")

Comment: No I still get the same error

Comment: can you post code how are you doing?

Comment: Sorry I misread your comment. How would I pass activity reference to adapter

Comment: From activity val adapter=RecycleViewAdapter(this)
From Fragment val adapter=RecycleViewAdapter(requireActivity())

Comment: The better approach for this issue is to create a callback (i.e interface) for your item click, pass that callback in the constructor of your adapter, implement that interface in your activity/fragment and then invoke that callback in a click of your view in the adapter. Find it on google, you will find many examples for that.